# Configure datasource in Heroku deployment with JNDI lookup

Tags: heroku, datasource, jndi

I am currently using JNDI lookup to get my datasource from Tomcat's context.xml for either MySQL or PostgreSQL.
My context.xml looks like this:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/MyDataSource"
          auth="Container"
          type="javax.sql.DataSource"
          username="user"
          password="pass"
          driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver"
          url="jdbc:postgresql://servername:5432/database"
          maxActive="20"
          maxIdle="10"
          validationQuery="Select 1"
/>
```

However, one of my clients is using **Heroku** for deployment and I am wondering how I can set my datasource there and how to read it from my Java web app using JNDI lookup.
In Heroku I am using the [heroku-deploy plugin with Tomcat](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/war-deployment)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the `context.xml` file to the `--context-xml` option of Webapp-runner, which is used by heroku-deploy. To do so, set a config var like this:

```
$ heroku config:set WEBAPP_RUNNER_OPTS="--context-xml context.xml"
```

Then when you deploy, include the `context.xml` file like this:

```
$ heroku deploy:war --war app.war --includes context.xml
```

This is described in detail in [Configuring WAR Deployment with the Heroku Toolbelt](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/configuring-war-deployment-with-the-heroku-toolbelt)

Comment: It seems to work, but I still get a NoInitialContextException as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33235127/noinitialcontextexception-heroku-war-deploy